# New data emit by socket.io is not take by AngularJS

Tags: sql, angularjs, node.js, socket.io

I have a NodeJs server with socket.io, my app is a chat I am using AngularJS as a client,  my problem is when I send a new data to my databases is saved correctly, but when I got to my client the data isn't refreshed itself,

on my client chatController

I have this

```
 socket.on(CHAT.GET_CHATS, instance.onChatsReceived);
```

I am calling this function

Receiving emitted object from socket server with all the data

```
    function onChatsReceived(chatsArr) {
        console.log(chatsArr);
        // decode messages for history array
        chatsArr.forEach(function (oneChat) {
            var parsed = JSON.parse(oneChat.members);
            var parsedSent = JSON.parse(oneChat.sentby);
            // console.log(parsedSent)
            var nick = parsedSent[0].lastseen;
            // console.log(nick);
            oneChat.isOnline = $scope.isOnline(parsedSent[0].lastseen);
            var decoded = htmlDecode(oneChat.message);
            oneChat.message = decoded;
            oneChat.members = parsed;
        });

        $scope.messagesCounted = true;

        $scope.$applyAsync(function () {
            $scope.chats = chatsArr;
            if ($scope.chats.length < 100 ) {
                $scope.loadMoreContacts = false;
            }
        });

    }
```

but my array of object doesn't change if I don't refresh the browser

after I insert the data my array coming from my socket

```
(18) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

after I insert the data and refresh my browser

(19) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]

It is like the socket.io emit the data but AngularJS is don't refresh it some can help me thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide the version of the Angular you're running ?

I'm pretty sure, this come from the necessity  that the functions of the original framework, need to be converted with the flavor suiting you ( Provider, Factory or Service ) to enter the digest loop .

Take a look at that tutorial for the Typescript version ( Angular2+ )

> https://tutorialedge.net/typescript/angular/angular-socket-io-tutorial/

Or that one for the AngularJS (1<) :

> https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/more-responsive-single-page-applications-with-angularjs-socketio-creating-the-library--cms-21738

Comment: Yes sure is angularjs 1.6.6 thanks for answer me back